# How to remove a field from a document

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The database schema:

```
{
    _id: "kun2",
    result150160: [10,20,30];
    moon: 4
}
```

I want to delete the whole field result150160 by the client with a variable:

```
var deleteresult = "result150160"
Box.update( {_id: this._id} , {$unset: { deleteresult } } );
```

Answer (score 13):

The correct syntax is this:

```
Box.update( {_id: this._id} , {$unset: { deleteresult : "" } } );
```

You have to specify a value for the `$unset` operation : `{ deleteresult : "" }`. Even if it is empty.

Checkout the [relevant docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/unset/):

> **`db.collection.update( { field: value1 }, { $unset: { field1: "" } } );`**
>   The above example deletes field1 in collection from documents where field has a value of value1. The value of the field in the $unset statement (i.e. "" above) does not impact the operation.

Comment: I've tested your syntax few minutes ago, but it doesn't work too

Comment: This is the correct syntax to use - you can see that from the link to the docs I included. Are you sure the problems doesn't lie somewhere else in your code? Does `Box` actually refer to a collection? Is the `_id` attribute correct?

Comment: @sebastian have you tried running running the command in the meteor mongo console. if it works, then it you're code that's broken.

Comment: It seems this problem persists in Meteor as of today. I tried $unset in my code and didn't work. I had to use an update to change the field to false, which represented the same in my case as unsetting the field, and worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var deleteresult = {};
deleteresult["result150160"] = true
Box.update( {_id: this._id} , {$unset: deleteresult } );
```

Basically you have to use a key value pair, it doesn't matter what you use for `true`, as long as theres something there.

Comment: That doesn't work and I don't want the string in the query, because result150160 was an example and also could be another string :)

Comment: I've slightly modified the syntax, you can use any string in place. Please also check your javascript console as it could also be something else that causes it to not work (`.allow` permissions or not having the `_id` in properly)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work for you:

```
var deleteresult = "result150160";    
var updateQuery={$unset:{}};   
updateQuery.$unset[deleteresult]=1;   
Box.update( {_id: this._id} ,updateQuery,false,true);
```